# Versionado de archivo en el resource de un ejecutable

Tags: c++, windows, qt, exe

tengo un programa echo con Qt4 cuya version es 1.0.0.0, pero lo porté a Qt5 y con pequeños cambios en la funcionalidad, no se cual numero de version debo incrementar.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Podrías replantearla de otra manera?

Comment: Basicamente tengo problemas, en comprender el significado de cada valor de version, entonces cuando uno hace cambios ¿cual valor se debe aumentar?
O sea cual es la semantica del versionado.
Pero creo que con los cambios y soluccion de bug, creo que la proxima version que utilizaré sera 1.1.0.0

Comment: El cambio de número de versión es completamente arbitrario y a gusto del equipo de desarrollo, pero puedes ver algunas guías en la [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning).